# How to build an installer for an Outlook 2010 add in using Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, windows-installer, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I have used Visual Studio 2012 to build an Outlook 2010 Add-In using the .NET 4.5 framework in C#. I'm trying to build an installer for this in order to distribute the Add-In both internally and external to our network. I have installed the suggested "InstallShield Limited Edition Project" and created an msi file, which I then tried to install on the target machine, but received an error stating that the dll file is not a valid Office Add-In. 8 files in total were installed, which include,

1. addin_file.dll.manifest
2. addin_file.vsto
3. addin_file.dll
4. addin_file.pdb
5. Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.v4.0.Utilities.xml
6. Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.xml
7. Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll
8. Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.v4.0.Utilities.dll

I assume there must be something that needs to be done to the installer in order to add entries into the registry but I'm not sure what this is. I have searched around but can only find articles relating to Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure that you included all the required prerequsites to the installer - VSTO runtime, .Net runtime and etc.

The [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) article describes all the required steps to deploy your add-in. Make sure that you did all the steps described in the article.

P.S. There is no need to deploy .pdb files on the end user PCs. They are used for debugging.

Comment: @PradeepPatel: If Eugene's answer solved your problem, would you consider marking it as such. The question/answer/reputation system is what drives StackOverflow (SO).